# --experimental_execution_log_file results in empty log file

Tags: bazel

In `bazel/rc/workspace.bazelrc` I have:

```
build --experimental_execution_log_file=experimental_execution.log
build --noexecution_log_sort
```

When bazel runs, it creates an `experimental_execution.log` file in the workspace root, but the file is empty no matter how much work bazel does.

Anyone encounter this and figure out what the problem is?

I tried specifying a full path to the log file but that had no impact.  It seems I have the filename configured correctly since bazel creates the file.  It just doesn't write any log output to it.

Comment: Can you share the error logs. May be thats reason your log file is empty.

Comment: There are no error logs.